# Can't open several tabs in Azure function App because functions-XXX.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I have FA in West Europe that have this network settings:

[image]

I can open some of the tabs and see the details under them without any type of problems, e.g.'Application Insight', 'Functions' tbs ,... etc. (I have marked some of them with green in the below image).

[image]

However, I have some problems with opening some other types of tabs like the 'configuration' tab (I have also marked some of them with red color in the above image).
The problem that I have is that: sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. Often, I see something like this when I open the configuration for example:

[image]

where the message in the middle of page varies each time I refresh the page. Some examples for the message/adress that I can see are:

```
functions-india-ame.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection.
functions-jp-west-ame.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection.
functions-db3-ame.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection.
functions-africa-ame.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection.
functions-australia-ame.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection.
functions-france-ame.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection.
functions-blu-ame.azurewebsites.net unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

However, sometimes when I continue refreshing the page, I can see the normal content of the page. i.e. something like this:

[image]

Any idea about why I have such problem and/or how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for this occurrence, including:

***Need to check & Resolve:***

- The administrator commonly controls some Azure functions/Portal settings, so in that case the selections will be greyed out as shown in your image.

  However, you're rarely facing issue to see these options. According to my workaround, it is solely a **server-related** issue.
- *Unexpectedly closing the connection:*

  It means that the server is restricting the connection.
  Check Network Tab and firewall by inspecting the web page or using devtools (F12/Fn+F12) to find where the root cause is.
- I am not sure which browser you are using but always prefer "***Edge***" to work with Azure portal services.

  I have created Azure Function Apps in multiple regions like *Central US, East US, West Europe, South India* etc. as there is no issue I found in
  opening in all the menu tabs of the Azure Function app portal menu even tested while connecting with Mobile Hotspot, Public Wi-Fi and corporate network.

[image]